# Using Vagrant to manage AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

For some time I am managing EC2 (Windows Boxes), RDS and S3 on AWS.

I do know manual steps that must be made in order to set up lets say a normal box (DB, Storage and Server. I heard about Vagrand, but everywhere I looked it mainly talks about Linux boxes on AWS.

My main question is: Is Vagrand a tool that will save me time for deyploment (windows), or should I not use it at all (in Windows scenario).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant plays nicely with AWS (via [vagrant-aws plugin](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws)).

Vagrant seems to play nicely with Windows as well [since version 1.6](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-windows.html) and the introduction of WinRM support (ssh alternative for Windows).

However AWS plugin [doesn't support WinRM communicator](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/180) yet. So you'll need to pre-bake your Windows AMIs with SSH service pre installed, if you want vagrant to provision it.

**Update (29/03/2016):** Thanks to Rafael Goodman for pointing to [vagrant-aws-winrm](https://github.com/rafd123/vagrant-aws-winrm) plugin as a possible workaround.

Comment: FWIW, I there's a vagrant plugin that facilitates WinRM support using the vagrant-aws plugin: https://github.com/rafd123/vagrant-aws-winrm There's also an issue/pull request to get this functionality into vagrant-aws proper: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/433